# Override defaults page option in apostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I would like to make the "published" option "false" by default, instead of "true".

I tried to had this in apostrophe-custom-pages :

But it does not work ! 
Could you give a hand ?

Thanks

EDIT : The complete index.js 
Maybe my default option is overrided elsewhere ?

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {

  extend: 'apostrophe-doc-type-manager',

  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {

options.name = options.name || self.__meta.name.replace(/\-pages$/, '-page');

if (options.permissionsFields === undefined) {
  // By default, pages have nuanced permissions
  options.permissionsFields = true;
}

options.addFields = [
  {
    type: 'boolean',
    name: 'published',
    label: 'Published',
    def:false
  },
    {
      type: 'slug',
      name: 'slug',
      label: 'Slug',
      required: true,
      // with this flag, a leading / is enforced, and slashes
      // elsewhere are allowed etc.
      page: true
    },
    {
      type: 'select',
      name: 'type',
      label: 'Type',
      required: true,
      choices: _.map(options.apos.pages.typeChoices, function(type) {
        return {
          value: type.name,
          label: type.label
        };
      })
    },
    {
      type: 'boolean',
      name: 'orphan',
      label: 'Hide in Navigation'
    }
].concat(options.addFields || []);

options.arrangeFields = [
  {
    name: 'basics',
    label: 'Basics',
    fields: [ 'meta-description', 'title', 'slug', 'type','alaune', 'color', 'published', 'tags', 'orphan' ]
  }
].concat(options.arrangeFields || []);

},

construct: function(self, options) {
require('./lib/dispatch.js')(self, options);
require('./lib/api.js')(self, options);
}
};
```

Haha I love this site but I cannot post my code without more comments arround it ! Well, my issue is very simple to explain.

So .. I can thanks the apostrophe-cms team for the good work ^^ And Tom for the patient support !

Comment: That should work. Did you put it in `beforeConstruct`? Please post more complete code. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Tom, 
Thks for the reply
Could this default option be overrided on another file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the publication status of a new page is inherited from its parent page. This is implemented in the `newChild` method of `apostrophe-pages`.

This is a pretty useful rule honestly, so you might want to just create your top-level pages, set them manually to be unpublished, and then take advantage of the rule for second-level pages etc.

Or, unpublish your home page for now and even the top-level pages will be born unpublished (obviously after launch you won't want to do that anymore).

But if neither of these scenarios really works for your needs, you can extend the `newChild` method via the "super pattern" to do what you want:

```
// in lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js of your own project.
// DO NOT modify it in node_modules, that is NEVER NECESSARY

module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    var superNewChild = self.newChild;
    self.newChild = function(parentPage) {
      var child = superNewChild(parentPage);
      child.published = false;
      return child;
    };
  }
};
```

We would consider a pull request to implement a flag like `unpublishNewChildPages` for the `apostrophe-pages` module. Then the above code could be part of the original implementation of `newChild`.

FYI the code you shared seems to be an excessively complete copy of the entire module, if you're only trying to override one thing you do not need to copy the entire module to project level (and you shouldn't, it makes you responsible for any changes we make later). Your project-level version of a core Apostrophe module automatically subclasses the original version, so you can override individual things without worrying about the original code - it will still run.